# SPD Designer workflow using REST API: How can I get a query result not tied to a specific result item?

Tags: rest, designer-workflow, dashboard-designer-2013

My goal is to use an SPD workflow that uses the REST API to copy a list item to another list when it gets created in the source list. I can get an item copied when the result item is specified in the Get statement **d/results(0)/Title**, but that only copies the first item in the list ... how do I define the result (d/results) to not be tied to a specific result item so that each list item created is copied with Title?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First set one workflow variable containing Current Item ID

[image]

Then use this workflow variable to call REST query for example

> http://server/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('List Title')/items?$filter=ID eq <Workflow Variable>

So it always return current created item..

Check and comment if you have any query...

Comment: Please up vote answer..

Comment: Can't vote answers yet